# Group by 2 data elements and then provide a count of values within an additional column for each group

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summary

Hi I have the below dataset and code.

```
 df <- 
  read.table(textConnection("Area   CustomerAge CustomersInGroup
    A 28 1
    A 40 3
    A 70 2
    A 19 4
    B 13 3
    B 12 2
    B 72 1
    B 90 7"), header=TRUE)


df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    # Create categories
    Customer_Age_Group = dplyr::case_when(
      CustomerAge <= 18            ~ "0-18",
      CustomerAge > 18 & CustomerAge <= 60 ~ "19-60",
      CustomerAge > 60             ~ ">60"
    ))

df2 %>% group_by(Area, Customer_Age_Group,.drop = FALSE) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  complete(Area, Customer_Age_Group, fill=list(n=0)) %>% 
  arrange(Area, parse_number(Customer_Age_Group))
```

Problem is that it provides a final count of applicable rows per group - I would like to amend this so instead the final count is of the values of 'CustomersInGroup' - e.g. for group A 19-60 this would sum to 8 (the values of the 3 rows) rather than the number of 3 representing the number of rows. Any help very much appreciated.

[image]

The final output should look like the below - totals of CustomersInGroup grouped by Area and then CustomerAge

| Area | CustomerAge | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0-18 | 0 |
| A | 19-60 | 8 |
| A | >60 | 2 |
| B | 0-18 | 5 |
| B | 19-60 | 0 |
| B | >60 | 8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `summarise` with `sum` to get the totals of CustomersInGroup. You can use the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    # Create categories
    Customer_Age_Group = dplyr::case_when(
      CustomerAge <= 18            ~ "0-18",
      CustomerAge > 18 & CustomerAge <= 60 ~ "19-60",
      CustomerAge > 60             ~ ">60"
    ))

df2 %>% 
  group_by(Area, Customer_Age_Group, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(Totals = sum(CustomersInGroup)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  complete(Area, Customer_Age_Group, fill=list(Totals=0)) %>% 
  arrange(Area, parse_number(Customer_Age_Group))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Area'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   Area  Customer_Age_Group Totals
#>   <chr> <chr>               <int>
#> 1 A     0-18                    0
#> 2 A     19-60                   8
#> 3 A     >60                     2
#> 4 B     0-18                    5
#> 5 B     19-60                   0
#> 6 B     >60                     8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use `cut` to create `Customer_Age_Group` using `cut` and `group_by` in turn, e.g.,

```
df %>%
  group_by(
    Area,
    Customer_Age_Group = cut(CustomerAge, c(0, 18, 60, Inf), labels = c("0-18", "19-60", ">60")), 
    .drop = FALSE
  ) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(CustomersInGroup)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

and you will obtain

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Area  Customer_Age_Group     n
  <chr> <fct>              <int>
1 A     0-18                   0
2 A     19-60                  8
3 A     >60                    2
4 B     0-18                   5
5 B     19-60                  0
6 B     >60                    8
```

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Aha, I forgot about that! Thanks for your reminder! Updated already!

Answer (score 0):

This gives what you want using the package **data.table**.

```r
library(data.table)
df <- 
  read.table(textConnection("Area   CustomerAge CustomersInGroup
    A 28 1
    A 40 3
    A 70 2
    A 19 4
    B 13 3
    B 12 2
    B 72 1
    B 90 7"), header=TRUE)

setDT(df)
df[ , Customer_Age_Group := ifelse(CustomerAge <= 18, "0-18",
                                   ifelse(CustomerAge > 18 & CustomerAge <= 60, "19-60", ">60"))]

out = df[ , .(sum_customers = sum(CustomersInGroup)), by = Customer_Age_Group]
out
#>    Customer_Age_Group sum_customers
#>                <char>         <int>
#> 1:              19-60             8
#> 2:                >60            10
#> 3:               0-18             5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but I require the data to be grouped by Area then by CustomerAge then by the sum of the values.